# How to open a fragment from another fragment using binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

How to open a `Fragment` from another `Fragment`?

I basically have a button inside of my `HomeFragment.kt` and I want to make it to redirect me to `AboutFragment` but I'm not sure how to make it. I tried different methods from Stack but nothing worked... Any suggestions? I wanna open the new fragment as I will open from navigation drawer.

Here is the button but my code just work with activities... Not with fragments...

```
binding.aboutUsBtn.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(activity, AboutFragment::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Are you using the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) (i.e., does your activity XML use a `NavHostFragment`)?

Comment: It's impossible to "open" a `Fragment`... for an "About" `Fragment`, a `DialogFragment` & `<dialog/>` tag in the nav-graph would permit to navigate (assuming Navigation Component).

Comment: Oh ... well ... it was worth trying. Thanks anyway :D I will adapt my app and see what's going on with the code below

Comment: Better try the Navigation Component; it generates navigation directions, similar to data-biniding: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Okay! I will try. Thanks so much for indications ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code plz:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_layout, new ChatFragment(), "second fragment"); //My second Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Is working but it overlap Home fragment with About Fragment. 

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you have been involved 